# Why and when to use Promise.resolve?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

As I know, Promises are used to represent success/failure of an asynchronous operation. When I am looking into one of my project, all the functions are wrapping the final result in 'Promise.resolve'. I am not understanding, what is the use of wrapping all the function results in 'Promise.resolve'. Is there any use case here?

For example, all the functions are following below template.

```
process = (data) => {
  //Perform some operations.
  return Promise.resolve(result);
}
```

Comment: what if you have a strategy pattern that expects a promise for a result, but you have a synchronous function?

Comment: [Don't return promises from otherwise synchronous functions!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45683984/1048572)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The only reason to use `Promise.resolve` is converting a value that *might* be a promise to a promise.

`Promise.resolve(value)` is a convenience method that does `new Promise(resolve => resolve(value)`. If the value is a promise it will be returned, if it is a promise from a userland promise library it will be converted to a native promise. If it is a plain value it will be converted for a promise fulfilled with that value.

```
Promise.resolve(5); // returns a promise fulfilled with the number 5.
```

This is useful in several cases, for example:
  - If a function *might* return a promise, it should always return a promise - so for example if you have a cached value it might need to be `Promise.resolve`d.
 - If there are multiple implementations of functionality and some are synchronous - it creates a uniform interface.

Note that in practice with `async` functions this is not needed so much anymore since an async function always returns a promise - even if you `return` a plain value (in fact, whatever you return from an async function is `Promise.resolve`d implicitly).

Also note that in particular you shouldn't make functions return promises if all they do is synchronous computation since a function returning a promise implies I/O in JavaScript.

Comment: Your first sentence is really not right.  That's not the ONLY reason to use `Promise.resolve()` as even your own cache example explains.  Sometimes you already have the value (which you know is NOT a promise), but need to return a promise that resolves to that value.  You could pick better wording for that first sentence.