# How to create a Promise from a variable?

Tags: javascript

I have a variable:

```
let x = 1;
```

What is the simplest way to create a Promise that will right away return the x ? Something like:

```
let promise = Promise(x);
```

The question is not about when and how to use Promises. It is clear.

Comment: `Promise.resolve(x)`

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? `const p = Promise.resolve(x)` will directly resolve the promise so you could do smth like: `p.then(.....)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why and when to use Promise.resolve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54723849/why-and-when-to-use-promise-resolve)

Comment: @KrzysztofKrzeszewski The question you mention is about something different. it is about when to use Promise.resolve, not about how to wrap variable into a Promise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You make a resolved promise like this:

```
let x = 1;
let promise = Promise.resolve(x);
```

Also you can make a rejected promise:

```
let rejectedPromise = Promise.reject(x);
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree with others `Promise.resolve` is a straightforward way to wrap a value into `Promise`. One more option is to use sync and async values inside function:

```
async function foo<T>(value: T): Promise<T> {
  // do something async
  // and/or return simple value
  return value;
}

const a: Promise<number> = foo(123);
const b: number = await foo(123);
```