# Is synchronous code in a Promise blocking?

Tags: javascript

```
function getPropsPromise(prop) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        resolve(prop());
    });
}
```

If I wrap a synchronous method in the above 'promisifying' function:

```
function docProps() {
    const data = {};
    data['doc.title'] = document.title;
    return data;
}
```

Like so:

```
getPropsPromise(docProps)
```

Does this constitute as a wrong application of Promises? Essentially, is it acceptable to use Promises for anything non-network related? If it is then would it be better to return a Promise directly from the 'docProps' function as follows or does 'promisifying' its call serve the same objective?:

```
function docProps() {
    const data = {};
    data['doc.title'] = document.title;
    return new Promise(resolve => { resolve(data) };
}
```

Comment: sure, why not, you could probably do with `return Promise.resolve( data )` though, or make the docProps `async` therefor implicitly make it return a promise... A long running method inside a promise is still blocking, seeing that javascript is single threaded, if really needed then you can use a webworker

Comment: It's definitely not wrong application of Promises, there is some libraries doing that already (like [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html) for example. I don't think either of your examples are better, it's just different, in first case you have generic function that can promisify any other function and can be reused, in 2nd it's just function returning promise

Comment: If you use a `Promise`, then it means you're trying to solve a problem and a `Promise` is the tool to do so. The problem that's solved via `Promise` is avoiding blocking the main thread until an I/O operation completes. In our browsers, networking and file reading are tasks that depend on the network or hard drive, and are much slower than computing tasks - thus, they would cause the browser to hang until finished. Unless you have two *"pieces"* that move at different speeds, then using a `Promise` doesn't really solve anything, nor does it break anything. Your examples don't need promises.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to wrap synchronous functions in to a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36826592/what-is-the-best-way-to-wrap-synchronous-functions-in-to-a-promise)

Answer (score 3):

> Does this constitute as a wrong application of Promises? Essentially, is it acceptable to use Promises for anything non-network related?

No, it is fine to use promises for non-network tasks. It's also used when reading files, with timeouts, asynchronous processing, with asynchronous steams, etc.

> If it is then would it be better to return a Promise directly from the 'docProps' function as follows or does 'promisifying' its call serve the same objective?:

They are equivalent, but it would be redundant if `docProps` returned a promise and you also wrapped it in a `getPropsPromise` promisif-ier. Also, your `getPropsPromise` can be replaced by the standard `Promise.prototype.resolve` method. I.e.,

```
function getPropsPromise(prop) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        resolve(prop());
    });
}

getPropsPromise(func);
```

is equivalent to

```
Promise.resolve(func());
```

Lastly, unless your `docProps` is a dummy/placeholder you created for this question, there's nothing asynchronous about it. There doesn't seem to be a need for promises at all in the snippets you provided.

Comment: Your last point is probably the most important here. The OPs code isn't doing anything async at all

Comment: You got it. I've been trying to relay your last point to my manager in a non-disrespectful way but can't seem to able to really point out that pulling existing data from the DOM is not thread-blocking. His prime example is that retrieving first-party cookies could take some time ergo it should be in a promise. Not that we will immediately disperse with the said data. As you said, there is no need for promises for docProps and such but on technical grounds, why not?

Comment: JS is not multi threaded and there are no performance benefits (in fact, some performance detriment due to overhead) to promises. Promises are meant to solve a syntax/readability issue with callbacks, not improve performance. That being said, if a synchronous function is slow but not necessary, rather than promisify it, you could loo into ensuring it's called after other more important functions have completed.

Comment: plus one for the `Promise.resolve(func());`

Answer (score 1):

If `docProps` is a regular synchronous function, then doing this gets you nothing except a slower program. Synchronous code in a Promise will still run on the same thread as all your other code, so it still blocks.

If `docProps` is asynchronous, then it either returns a promise or takes a callback. If it returns a promise, wrapping it in another promise is an anti-pattern. If it takes a callback, then the correction pattern would be to call `resolve` in the callback with something like:

```
function getPropsPromise(prop) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
      prop(() => {
        /* do stuff */
        resolve(/*something*/)
      });
  });
}
```

So either way, it's hard to see a good use case for the code as posted unless you have something the expects a promise and you only have a synchronous function. In that case you're probably better off with `Promise.resolve()`